# Grunt Watch not observing any changes to any file aside from html files

Tags: sass, gruntjs, task, watch

Here is a basic view of my "watch" grunt task:

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
    require("matchdep").filterDev("grunt-*").forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);
    grunt.initConfig({
      watch: {
          options: {
            livereload: true,
          },
        gruntfile:{
            files:['gruntfile.js'],
            tasks:['default']
        },
        html: {
            files: ['index.html', 'assets/templates/*.html'],
            tasks: ['default']
        },
        js: {
            files: ['assets/js/*.js'],
            tasks: ['default']
        },
        sass: {
            options:{
                livereload:false
            },
            files:['assets/sass/*.scss'],
            tasks:['buildcss'],
        },
        css:{
            files:['assets/sass/*.scss'],
            tasks:[]
        },
      },
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['htmlhint','buildjs', 'buildcss', 'browserSync', 'watch','serve']);
};
```

So I have buildcss that compiles and minifies my scss into a master.css file. I've set up watch to watch the scss for changes, run the buildcss task, and then run the default task once the master.css file is updated. Then it should then refresh the page. 
However, whenever I make a change to the scss file and save it, terminal shows no file updates even though it is apparently "watching files...". The only files that show as updated when I make changes are the html files: index and templates. It makes no sense to me. Sorry, I'm configuring Grunt for the first time here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was confusing watch and browserSync instead of using them together. First, I had to add watchTask: true, to browserSync, then I had to ensure that browserSync was being called before watch, and then I had to add the snippet of code the console prodded me to add to my index.html. Now it works perfectly. Here is the site I used to find my way: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/getting-started-with-grunt